# Variance of Uniform Distribution vs Any other Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider two distributions P1x and P2x over X. Let P1x be a uniform distribution and P2x be any other distribution. Can we say that

```
Variance of P1 >= Variance of P2
```

Comment: What is a distribution "over $X$"? If by $X$ you mean a random variable, then $X$ has one probability distribution; there can't be two different probability distributions of the same random variable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I considered X as range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the case.  Consider $X = [0,1]$, then the uniform distribution has variance $1/12$ while the distribution $P_2(0) = P_2(1) = 1/2$ has variance $1/4$.